# Keep element in view while scrolling

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, scrollviewer

Simpel question, I have a windows phone page that contains a `scrollviewer` with inside it an `image`, a `textblock` and a `richtextbox`.

Now when the user starts scrolling I want to keep the `textblock` in view on top when the `image` has scrolled outside the page.

So the effect is, user starts scrolling upwards, everything scrolls upwards, when the image is outside the page, the textblock stays at the top of the page but the richtextbox keeps scrolling upwards.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to reach this result:

First, the layout. I've set a grid, with two rows. The first is empty, and will host the header when we need to freeze it. The second row contains the scrollviewer.

Inside the scrollviewer, I've put the controls in a grid, but you can use whatever container suits you.

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1"
                Margin="0"
                Padding="0"
                x:Name="ParentScroll"
                ManipulationMode="Control"
                MouseMove="ParentScroll_MouseMove">
    <Grid x:Name="ChildGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Image Source="Picture.jpg" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Header" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="TextHeader" />
        <RichTextBox Grid.Row="2" x:Name="RichText">
            <Paragraph>
                <Bold>RichTextBox</Bold>
                <!-- More stuff -->
            </Paragraph>
        </RichTextBox>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I use the `MouseMove` event to be notified of the scrolling event. You can also dig into the template, extract the `ScrollBar` control, and subscribe to the `ValueChanged` event, as described here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/81fcd34e-6ec9-48d0-891e-c53a53344553/scrollviewer-synchronization

Note that you need to set `ManipulationMode` to `Control` or the position of the controls won't be updated at a smooth rate. I guess it's due to some internal optimization.

In the code behind, I use the `TransformToVisual` method to compute the relative position of the controls to the ScrollViewer. This way, I can know when the header goes out of view. When it does, I remove it from the child grid, and put it outside of the ScrollViewer, in the parent grid. When the top of the RichTextBox goes out of view, I put the header back into the ScrollViewer:

```
private void ParentScroll_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (Grid.GetRow(this.TextHeader) == 1)
    {
        var generalTransform = TextHeader.TransformToVisual(ParentScroll);
        var childToParentCoordinates = generalTransform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));

        if (childToParentCoordinates.Y < 0)
        {
            this.ChildGrid.Children.Remove(this.TextHeader);
            this.ParentGrid.Children.Add(this.TextHeader);

            Grid.SetRow(this.TextHeader, 0);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var generalTransform = RichText.TransformToVisual(ParentScroll);
        var childToParentCoordinates = generalTransform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));

        if (childToParentCoordinates.Y > 0)
        {
            this.ParentGrid.Children.Remove(this.TextHeader);
            this.ChildGrid.Children.Add(this.TextHeader);

            Grid.SetRow(this.TextHeader, 1);
        }
    }
```

There may be less-hacky ways to reach the same results, but this solution seems to work smoothly in the emulator.

Comment: Hey KooKiz, it's a nice approach, but I'm going for my own solution ;)

Comment: @Depechie Just make sure to put your own answer on StackOverflow, for future reference ;)

Comment: I checked this solution again! If you use the ValueChanged event of the VerticalScrollBar this solution works smooth! And with it you don't need to worry about the Compression of the scrollviewer because the title is inside of it!

Comment: @KooKiz Do either of these approaches work in Windows Store 8.1 apps? Windows Store app doesn't have ManipulationMode="Control"

Answer (score 1):

I've found a working solution myself... the complete detail is available on my [blog here...](http://depblog.weblogs.us/2013/08/27/fixing-header-when-scrolling-content-on-windows-phone-page/) it contains also the link to my demo project on GitHub.

The trick was to get hold of the `VerticallScrollBar` inside the `ScrollViewer` and to set the `ManipulationMode` to `Control` to get enough feedback on the UI thread.
With the scroll offset information of the scrollbar we than animate the specific ui element we want to keep in view.