# Prevent element from disappearing when scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, .net-4.0

I'd like to prevent a button (ButtonExpander) from moving outside a ListBox's viewport after it has been clicked, until it's clicked again. The button's parent must be visible (with enough room for the button), and the button cannot leave the bounds of the usercontrol it belongs to. If either of those conditions aren't met, the button goes back to its normal behavior. Any ideas on how to best accomplish this?

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        x:Name="WinMain"
        x:Class="MainWindow"
        Title="Window"
        Height="500"
        Width="680"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Margin="0"
        MaxWidth="700">
    <Window.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Black"     Offset="0.27"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF2E2E2E" Offset="0.105"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF1D1D1D" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Black"     Offset="0.91"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Window.Background>
        <Grid x:Name="GridMain">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="40" MaxHeight="40" MinHeight="40"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="34" MinHeight="34" MaxHeight="34"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Menu"        Grid.Row="0" Fill="#FF5F5F5F"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="SomeButtons" Grid.Row="1" Fill="#FF303243"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="LbFancy"
                 Margin="10"
                 Grid.Row="2"
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                 Focusable="False"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}">#00000000</SolidColorBrush>
            </ListBox.Resources>
        </ListBox>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Status" Grid.Row="3" Fill="#FF303243"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.vb**

```
Class MainWindow
    Dim CurrentMapArray() As String = {"01_FooBar", "02_BarFoo", "03_OofRab", "04_Rab_Oof", "07_Santa", "08_Cat"}
    Public Sub New()
        'This call is required by the designer
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Build()
        'All Maps item
        Dim mapinfodef As MapInfo = New MapInfo
        LbFancy.Items.Add(mapinfodef)
        LbFancy.Items.GetItemAt(0)
        mapinfodef.MapTitleInternal.Text = ""
        mapinfodef.MapTitle.Text = "All Maps"
        For Each map As String In CurrentMapArray
            Dim mapinfotemp As MapInfo = New MapInfo
            'Set basic values for element properties, etc
            LbFancy.Items.Add(mapinfotemp)
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub Main() Handles WinMain.Loaded
        Build()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The ListBox gets populated via code behind with dozens of copies of the following user control:

**MapInfo.xaml**

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="MapInfo"
    x:Name="Mapinfo"
    Margin="0,2,3,0" 
    MinWidth="600" 
    MinHeight="77">
    <Grid x:Name="GridRoot" Height="77" Background="Black">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="563"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="MapCanvas">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="112" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="451" Width="451"/>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="36" MaxWidth="36"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="25" MaxHeight="25"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="25" MaxHeight="25"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="25" MaxHeight="25"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Height="62"
                    Width="102"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.RowSpan="3"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    BorderBrush="White"
                    Margin="5,6,0,6"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    CornerRadius="1"
                    BorderThickness="1">
            </Border>
            <TextBlock x:Name="MapTitle"
                       Text="Map Title"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Foreground="White"
                       Margin="10,0.725,0,0.725"
                       FontSize="36"
                       Grid.Row="0" 
                       Grid.RowSpan="2"
                       Panel.ZIndex="2"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="MapTitleInternal"
                       Text="##_MapTitle"
                       Grid.Row="2"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Foreground="White"
                       Margin="10,4.354,0,4.353"
                       Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
            <Grid x:Name="MapInfoExt"
                  Grid.Row="3"
                  Grid.RowSpan="2"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  Width="559"
                  Panel.ZIndex="2">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#00000000" Opacity="0"/>
                </Grid.Background>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Rectangle x:Name="Item1" Grid.Row="0" Height="100" Fill="Red"    Opacity="0.15"/>
                <Rectangle x:Name="Item2" Grid.Row="1" Height="201" Fill="Green"  Opacity="0.15"/>
                <Rectangle x:Name="Item3" Grid.Row="2" Height="182" Fill="Blue"   Opacity="0.15"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="MapPanel"
              Margin="0,1,1,0"
              MinHeight="73"
              MinWidth="35"
              MaxWidth="35"
              Grid.Column="1"
              Panel.ZIndex="1">
            <Grid.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black"     Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF5F5F5F" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Black"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Grid.Background>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MaxHeight="30" MinHeight="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MaxHeight="8"  MinHeight="8"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      Panel.ZIndex="1"
                      Grid.Row="0"
                      BorderThickness="0.5"
                      Margin="0,9,0,0"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Rectangle Stroke="Black"
                       Panel.ZIndex="2"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       Margin="0,-1,0,1" 
                       Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
            <Button x:Name="ButtonExpander"
                    Panel.ZIndex="1"
                    Click="ButtonExpand_Click"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    Height="24"
                    Width="24"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Margin="5"/>
        </Grid>
        <Border x:Name="MapBorder"
                BorderThickness="1"
                BorderBrush="#FF0E363C"
                UseLayoutRounding="False"
                RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                Margin="0"
                Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**MapInfo.vb**

```
Imports System.Windows.Controls

Public Class MapInfo
    Inherits UserControl
    Dim _expanded As Boolean = False

    Private Sub ButtonExpand_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
        If _expanded = True Then
            _expanded = False
            GridRoot.Height = 77
            MapBorder.Tag = ""
            Dim rotateTransform1 As New RotateTransform(0)
            rotateTransform1.CenterX = 12
            rotateTransform1.CenterY = 12
            ButtonExpander.RenderTransform = rotateTransform1
            Return
        Else
            _expanded = True
            GridRoot.Height = 1545
            MapBorder.Tag = "Expanded"
            Dim rotateTransform1 As New RotateTransform(180)
            rotateTransform1.CenterX = 12
            rotateTransform1.CenterY = 12
            ButtonExpander.RenderTransform = rotateTransform1
            Return
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

ButtonExpander sets the height of GridRoot when clicked. The grid can get pretty big, so after the button's clicked, I'd like it to stay visible inside the ListBox, and slide up/down the gray area on the right-side of the window. Basically the same deal as the yellow box (similar questions, formatting help, etc.) on the right side of this webpage, or jQuery plugins like [this](http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/keep-element-in-view-while-scrolling-using-jquery/) (social widget thinger).

The only similar questions I could find that was related to C#/VB.NET is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424301/keep-element-in-view-while-scrolling), but the answers don't really help--one was for WinPhone and I couldn't view any code, and the other answer was for a scrollviewer, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that with a ListBox.

I would appreciate any help, doesn't have to be anything fancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your extended description, there is no elegant way to do this. A solution that will get you close is as follows.

In the MapInfo control xaml, remove the button from its current position and add a canvas with the button in it to the end of the GridRoot like follows.

```
<Border x:Name="MapBorder" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF0E363C" UseLayoutRounding="False" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="0" Panel.ZIndex="1" />
<Canvas Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Panel.ZIndex="1">
    <Button x:Name="ButtonExpander" Panel.ZIndex="1" Click="ButtonExpand_Click" Height="24" Width="24" Margin="5" Canvas.Right="10" Canvas.Top="24" />
</Canvas>
```

This will allow you to position the button within the MapInfo control.

In the MainWindow xaml, handle the ScrollView.ScrollChanged event

```
<ListBox x:Name="LbFancy"
         Margin="10"
         Grid.Row="2"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
         ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
         ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="ScrollViewer_OnScrollChanged"
         Focusable="False"
         VerticalAlignment="Center"
         HorizontalAlignment="Center">
```

Then in the ScrollViewer_OnScrollChanged event handler, manage the position of button within the control using code like

```
Private Sub ScrollViewer_OnScrollChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ScrollChangedEventArgs)

    For Each item As MapInfo In LbFancy.Items
        If (item.Expanded) Then

            Dim positionTransform = item.TransformToAncestor(LbFancy)
            Dim itemPosition = positionTransform.Transform(New Point(0, 0))

            If ((itemPosition.Y > 0) And (itemPosition.Y < e.ViewportHeight)) Then
                ' The top of the item is visible
            ElseIf ((itemPosition.Y < 0) And (itemPosition.Y + item.ActualHeight - button.Height > 0)) Then
                ' the top of the item is not visible but a part of the item is
                Dim button = CType(item.FindName("ButtonExpander"), Button)
                Canvas.SetTop(button, 0 - itemPosition.Y)
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

There is a bit more to be done around the positioning of the button, both at control creation and during scrolling, but this should get you started.

NOTE: Exception handling and null checking have been removed for brevity.

I hope this helps.

Comment: One other thing. I would consider using an MVVM pattern. Your CInfo user control would become a model class and a DataTemplate. The model class would exist in an ObservableCollection on your ViewModel which is bound to the ItemsSource of the ListBox, The DataTemplate would be assigned to the ItemsTemplate property of the ListBox. This will help separate your UI from your data. I have added this comment to give you some of the buzz words around WPF DataBinding with MVVM.

Comment: Yes, basically the button stays within the the viewport(?) of the ListBox, but there are conditions: the button's parent must be visible (with enough room for the button), and the button cannot leave the bounds of the usercontrol it belongs to. If either of those conditions aren't met, the button goes back to its normal behavior. I updated the question with more info and (hopefully) a clearer description of what I'm trying to accomplish. I can add some screenshots if that would help? MVVM stuff is something I'm trying to learn, but one thing at a time. :]

Comment: Modified the answer to take into account the modified question. I hope it helps.

Comment: Works great, thanks a bunch. I also learned a bit as well: difference between drawing.point/windows.point, property statement (never used it much), findname, etc.